# Sum of telescoping series

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

How can you change this series into a telescoping series so then you can find its sum?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: Just a general check before you proceed: Is this series convergent?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: no it does not converge do to a limit comparison test with $1/\sqrt n$

Answer (score 5):

Multiply by conjugate on top and bottom.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1}} \frac{\sqrt n -\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}$$

$$=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$

So,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)=\sqrt{N+1}-\sqrt{1}$$

Comment: so the denominator all cancels out?

Comment: which shows that the series does not converge, but has nice partial sum, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+1}}=\sqrt{n+1}-1$

Comment: In the denominator we have the difference of two squares. $(\sqrt{n})^2-(\sqrt{n+1})^2=n-(n+1)=-1$ @bjp409